# At end of JS function declaration, adding semicolon, why jshint prompt an error

Tags: javascript, jshint

When I declared a js function, and added a semicolon at the end, which is:
`function foo(){};`

Then jshint prompted **unnecessary semicolon**. Why?

Answer (score 4):

A function (or class) declaration is a complete statement; it should not have a semicolon.

You only need a semicolon for regular executable statements (including `const x = function() { ... };`).

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 types of function writting

- function declaration (; not allowed)
- function expression (; allowed)

see the below example

```
function _functionName() {

};  // this is not required



var _functionName = function() {

}; //this is okey
```

Comment: I guess you invented the terms by yourself?

Comment: see the difference T https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting

Comment: So what you mean is *function expression* , not *function express* .

Comment: ;) there was a typo. sorry about that. actually its function expression

Comment: "not allowed" !== "not required" !== "not necessary"